# Set different button layouts for different classes?

Tags: day-of-defeat

Is there a way to set up different keys for different classes? I like to be support (BAR) but a lot of times I press the right button in the middle of a fight, therefore switching to single fire.

But in the assault class and sniper it is necessary to have as the right button.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in Team Fortress 2, there doesn't appear to be class-specific configuration files in the games content directory. So, it doesn't appear that there is an automatic way to do this. You may, however, be able to do it manually:

Let's say every time you switched to class A, you wanted the **O** key be bound to `+attack`. But for the other classes, you wanted the **P** key to be bound to `+attack`. You can do this with an alias. Go into your Day of Defeat content folder (*Steam/steamapps/#your-username#/day of defeat source/dod/cfg*) and create a file called *autoexec.cfg* (if it's already there, thats okay). This will run automatically when the game starts. Open up the file, and type (if theres already something in it, just type at the bottom):

```
alias "+playClassA" "bind o +attack; unbind p"
alias "-playClassA" "bind p +attack; unbind o"
```

Now, every time you want to play class A, in the console you must type `+playClassA`. When you're done, you type `-playClassA`. When you use `+playClassA`, it will bind **O** to `+attack` and unbind **P**. When your use `-playClassA`, it will bind **P** to `+attack` and unbind **O**.

Sorry if this isn't what you were looking for, but it's faster than typing the `bind` and `unbind` commands into the console individually.